# Splitting and Merging large files (size in GB) in Java

Tags: java, file, io, merge, split

Suppose,

- I am splitting **2590400 KB** (approx 2.5 GB) file in 30 parts.
- It will produce 30 files with size of **86347 KB**.
  Which seems correct, 2590400/30 = 86346.66666667
- Now if I merge all the parts (30) again it is producing the file of **3453873 KB** file, which should be **2590410 KB**.

Can anyone help me why this difference is there? I am using below code for merge and split files.

**SplitFile.java**

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

/**
 * @author vishal.zanzrukia
 * 
 */
public class SplitFile {

    public static final String INPUT_FILE = "D:\\me\\projects\\input\\file\\path.txt";
    public static final int NUMBER_OF_OUTPUT_FILES = 30;
    public static final String FILE_SUFFIX = ".txt";

    /**
     * split file
     * 
     * @throws Exception
     */
    static void splitFile() throws Exception{

        File inputFile = new File(INPUT_FILE + "_Splits");
        inputFile.mkdir();

        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(INPUT_FILE, "r");

        long sourceSize = raf.length();
        long bytesPerSplit = sourceSize / NUMBER_OF_OUTPUT_FILES;
        long remainingBytes = sourceSize % NUMBER_OF_OUTPUT_FILES;

        int maxReadBufferSize = 8 * 1024; // 8KB
        for (int destIx = 1; destIx <= NUMBER_OF_OUTPUT_FILES; destIx++) {
            BufferedOutputStream bw = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(INPUT_FILE + "_Splits\\split." + destIx + FILE_SUFFIX));
            if (bytesPerSplit > maxReadBufferSize) {
                long numReads = bytesPerSplit / maxReadBufferSize;
                long numRemainingRead = bytesPerSplit % maxReadBufferSize;
                for (int i = 0; i < numReads; i++) {
                    readWrite(raf, bw, maxReadBufferSize);
                }
                if (numRemainingRead > 0) {
                    readWrite(raf, bw, numRemainingRead);
                }
            } else {
                readWrite(raf, bw, bytesPerSplit);
            }
            bw.close();
        }
        if (remainingBytes > 0) {
            BufferedOutputStream bw = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("split." + NUMBER_OF_OUTPUT_FILES + 1));
            readWrite(raf, bw, remainingBytes);
            bw.close();
        }
        raf.close();
    }

    /**
     * join file
     * 
     * @throws Exception
     */
    static void joinFiles() throws Exception{
        int maxReadBufferSize = 8 * 1024; 

        BufferedOutputStream bw = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(INPUT_FILE + "_Splits\\fullJoin" + FILE_SUFFIX));
        File inputFileDir = new File(INPUT_FILE + "_Splits");
        RandomAccessFile raf = null;
        if(inputFileDir.isDirectory()){
            for(File file : inputFileDir.listFiles()){
                raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
                long numReads = raf.length() / maxReadBufferSize;
                long numRemainingRead = raf.length()  % maxReadBufferSize;
                for (int i = 0; i < numReads; i++) {
                    readWrite(raf, bw, maxReadBufferSize);
                }
                if (numRemainingRead > 0) {
                    readWrite(raf, bw, numRemainingRead);
                }
                raf.close();
            }
        }
        bw.close();
    }

    public static void mergeFiles() {

        File[] files = new File[NUMBER_OF_OUTPUT_FILES];
        for(int i=1;i<=NUMBER_OF_OUTPUT_FILES;i++){
            files[i-1] = new File(INPUT_FILE + "_Splits\\split."+i+FILE_SUFFIX);
        }

        String mergedFilePath = INPUT_FILE + "_Splits\\fullJoin" + FILE_SUFFIX;


        File mergedFile = new File(mergedFilePath);

        mergeFiles(files, mergedFile);
    }

    public static void mergeFiles(File[] files, File mergedFile) {

        FileWriter fstream = null;
        BufferedWriter out = null;
        try {
            fstream = new FileWriter(mergedFile, true);
             out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (File f : files) {
            System.out.println("merging: " + f.getName());
            FileInputStream fis;
            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

                String aLine;
                while ((aLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    out.write(aLine);
                    out.newLine();
                }

                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        try {
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
//      splitFile();
        mergeFiles();
    }

    static void readWrite(RandomAccessFile raf, BufferedOutputStream bw, long numBytes) throws IOException {
        byte[] buf = new byte[(int) numBytes];
        int val = raf.read(buf);
        if (val != -1) {
            bw.write(buf);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, It's not possible to open such big file with any of my editors :(

Comment: Try Glogg (http://glogg.bonnefon.org/download.html) or 010Editor(http://www.sweetscape.com/010editor/)... 010Notepad opens everything... But need to pay for it, but trial version

Comment: You should try a smaller test case - try smaller file with similar contents, or only look at the first 10K of the big file for example. Then you can inspect the output yourself and see where the problems are.

Comment: Why are you suddenly reading by line using a reader instead of by bytes like how you split the file. Your `joinFiles` method looks much better than your `mergeFiles` method, except it will merge the files possibly in the wrong order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use your `joinFiles` method: don't try to read a file by line-by-line using a `Reader` if you want to keep it exactly like it was, because line endings may differ by platform.

Instead read them as a binary file using an `InputStream` or `RandomAccessFile` and write using an `OutputStream`.

The only problem in your `joinFiles` method is that it used `File.listFiles()` which makes no guarantees about the order in which the files are returned.

I combined your `mergeFiles()` code with `joinFiles()` to make this work (remember to invoke `joinFiles()` instead of `mergeFiles()` from your `main` method)

```
static void joinFiles(File[] files) throws Exception {
    int maxReadBufferSize = 8 * 1024;

    BufferedOutputStream bw = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(INPUT_FILE + "_Splits\\fullJoin"
            + FILE_SUFFIX));

    RandomAccessFile raf = null;
    for (File file : files) {
        raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
        long numReads = raf.length() / maxReadBufferSize;
        long numRemainingRead = raf.length() % maxReadBufferSize;
        for (int i = 0; i < numReads; i++) {
            readWrite(raf, bw, maxReadBufferSize);
        }
        if (numRemainingRead > 0) {
            readWrite(raf, bw, numRemainingRead);
        }
        raf.close();

    }
    bw.close();
}

public static void joinFiles() throws Exception {

    File[] files = new File[NUMBER_OF_OUTPUT_FILES];
    for (int i = 1; i <= NUMBER_OF_OUTPUT_FILES; i++) {
        files[i - 1] = new File(INPUT_FILE + "_Splits\\split." + i + FILE_SUFFIX);
    }

    joinFiles(files);
}
```

Comment: Hi Erwin, Thank you so much, I have tried `joinFiles` before `mergeFile` but I was getting problems while using that file, but I was not able to get what is problem with file. but Now I got the problem you mentioned is **Order of file**

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the very last line of code:

```
static void readWrite(RandomAccessFile raf, BufferedOutputStream bw, long numBytes) throws IOException {
    byte[] buf = new byte[(int) numBytes];
    int val = raf.read(buf);
    if (val != -1) {
        bw.write(buf);
    }
}
```

When you write, you write back `numBytes` of data, but the `read` function has [usefully returned](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#read(byte[])):

> *the total number of bytes read into the buffer*, or -1 if there is no more data because the end of this file has been reached.

Therefore, your fix is to [use a different `write`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html#write(byte[],%20int,%20int)):

```
bw.write(buf, 0 val);
```

Comment: That would be a problem if he was reading from sockets, pipes, or the console. But he's reading from a `RandomAccessFile` and not beyond the end, so it's not a problem (although what you propose is definitely nicer code)

Comment: Actually, I reviewed his calls to `readWrite`, and I think you are correct! I'd personally get rid of the calculation of `numRead`s and have `readWrite` return false when `val` becomes `-1`.